# Android DatePickerDialog parameters

Tags: java, android

I'm creating button dynamically at runtime which their click event opens a datepickerdialog. So like this:

```
Button btnDate = new Button(this);
btnDate.setText("Date");
btnDate.setTag(new UDAControlItemTag(q.getiQuestionID(),-1,f.getiSectionID(),f.getiGroup(),-1,"Date",""));
btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                         
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Button tempBtn = (Button)v;
    UDAControlItemTag tempQ = (UDAControlItemTag)tempBtn.getTag();
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_Question);    
    //tempBtn.setText(Integer.toString(mTempMonth));
    }
});
```

Then I have the listener where i can get the values and stuff but because I'm creating the controls dynamically, i keep these values of each control in an ArrayList with different properties. The issue I have is how to get the parameters i need to correctly determine which button was clicked in order to put in the correct properties for that question into the ArrayList.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerQuestion =  
   new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {  
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,  
             int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {  
             mTempYear = year;
             mTempMonth = monthOfYear;
             mTempDay = dayOfMonth;
         }

};
```

So in there i have the value of the dialog, but i need to have a QuestionID which is associated to the button that the user clicked, in order to put the value into the ArrayList of all the answers for all that dynamic controls on the activity. I'd really appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that listener you could use your own class that implements the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` interface and also has a constructor that takes an `int`, the `QuestionID`. Something like this:

```
public class TheSpecialListener implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private int id;

        public TheSpecialListener(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mTempYear = year;
            mTempMonth = monthOfYear;
            mTempDay = dayOfMonth;
            // id is the QuestionID so you now can identify the Button that started the dialog
        }

    };
```

Now when you click a `Button` you'll update a field with that `Button`'s QuestionID that will be used in the `onCreateDialog` method(which I don't know how you implemented):

```
private int questionId;
```

and in the `Button` listener:

```
//...
Button tempBtn = (Button)v;
UDAControlItemTag tempQ = (UDAControlItemTag)tempBtn.getTag();
questionId = //here pass the Button's id or whatever
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_Question);
```

and in the `onCreateDialog` method instantiate the above special listener and pass it the questionId field which will hold the identifier, as it will be updated each time a Button is clicked:

```
DatePickerDialog spd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new TheSpecialListener(questionId), 2012, 6, 16);
```